# How do you add a virtual network IP address from the kernel command-line?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, ethernet

I would like to add a virtual IP address, something you normal do with:

```
ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.1.1
```

(or via `/etc/network/interfaces`).  But, I'd like to do it from the kernel command-line, which has the command format:

```
ip=<client-ip>:<server-ip>:<gw-ip>:<netmask>:<hostname>:<device>:<autoconf>:<dns0-ip>:<dns1-ip>
```

However, the format for virtual IP names uses a colon, which is in conflict with the kernel command-line format.  So for example, the following non-virtual device `eth0` works:

```
ip=192.168.1.1:::::eth0:::
```

But if I want to use the virtual device `eth0:0`, the following does not work:

```
ip=192.168.1.1:::::eth0:0:::
```

(and I wouldn't expect it to, as the extra colon mucks with the format).  Note: doesn't work in this case means it still configures the `eth0` device, not the `eth0:0` device.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible.

The [kernel documentation for the `ip` parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/nfs/nfsroot.txt) says the syntax is

```
ip=<client-ip>:<server-ip>:<gw-ip>:<netmask>:<hostname>:<device>:<autoconf>:<dns0-ip>:<dns1-ip>
```

with only one `client-ip`.

The [Linux IP-Aliasing doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/alias.txt) says that the colon form is deprecated.

And the `ip` option simply treats `:` as a word separator without providing any special way to escape a literal `:`.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/ipconfig.c#L1614